# Learning C: K&R 1-22: 'fold'. Is this solution very unwieldy?

Tags: c

This exercise gave me some trouble, but I think I have a solution here that fulfils the spec. However it's very long compared to what I'm looking at on the solutions page at [clc-wiki.net](http://www.clc-wiki.net/wiki/KR2_Exercise_1-22).

In the course of solving the problem I loop over my buffered line three or four times. This seems like quite a lot, and the various edge cases I have to account for means my prog is over 100 lines long (including spacing).

If anyone is kind enough to have patience to read it, I'd really appreciate your thoughts. Could it be shorter? Are there any glaring redundancies?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOLD 20

int getline( char s[], int max );
int does_line_have_blanks( char line[], int len );
int locate_last_space ( char line[], int len );
int find_split( char line[], int len, int offset);
int mark_split_and_clean_trailing_spaces( char line[], int len, int spacecount );
int print_with_split( char s[], int split_pos );

int main()
{
  int len, i, split_pos, offset;
  char line[FOLD+1];

  len = split_pos = 0;
  for ( i = 0; i < FOLD+1; ++i )
    line[i] = 0;
  offset = 0; /*keeps track of characters that overflow the split so next buffer may be shortened accordingly*/

  while ( ( len = getline(line, (FOLD+1) - offset) ) > 0 ) {

    split_pos = find_split ( line, len, offset );

    offset = print_with_split( line, split_pos );

    /* clean out buffer*/
    for ( i = 0; i < FOLD+1; ++i )
      line[i] = '\0';
  }
  return 0;
}

int getline ( char s[], int max ) /* doesn't add newlines as K&R's does */
{
  int i, c;

  for (i = 0 ; i < max-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++ )
    s[i] = c;
  s[i] = '\0';

  return i;
}

int find_split( char line[], int len, int offset ) {

    int i, split_pos, blanks;

    i = split_pos = 0;

    /*make sure there are blanks - if not the line will be printed as-is*/ 
    blanks = does_line_have_blanks( line, len );

    if ( len < FOLD-offset || blanks != 1 ) {
      split_pos = len; /* hit a newline or EOF - split at end of input */
    } else {
      split_pos = locate_last_space( line, len );
    }
    return split_pos;
}

int does_line_have_blanks( char line[], int len ) {

  int i, blanks;

  i = blanks = 0;

  for ( i = 0; i < len; ++i )  { /*len is at null char in line*/
    if (line[i] == ' ' )
      blanks= 1;
  }
  return blanks;
}

int locate_last_space ( char line[], int len ) {

  int i, inspace, spacecount, split_pos;

  inspace = spacecount = split_pos = 0;

  for ( i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
    if ( line[i] == ' ' ) {
      inspace = 1;
      ++spacecount;
    } else {
      inspace = 0;
      if ( spacecount > 0 ) { /*if we leave inspace state, split on the preceding char */
        spacecount = 0;
        split_pos = i -1;
      }
    }
  }

  if ( inspace == 1 ) { /* and if we left in a space... */
    split_pos = mark_split_and_clean_trailing_spaces( line, len, spacecount );
  }

  return split_pos;
}

int mark_split_and_clean_trailing_spaces( char line[], int len, int spacecount ) {

  int split_pos, i;

  split_pos = i = 0;

  split_pos = len - spacecount; /*... split where it started */
  for ( i = split_pos + 1; i < len; ++i ) { /*nullify trailing spaces as per instructions*/
    line[i] = '\0';
  } 

  return split_pos;
}

int print_with_split( char line[], int split_pos ) {

   int i, offset;

   offset = 0;

   for ( i = 0; i < split_pos; ++i ) {
      putchar(line[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    for ( i = (split_pos + 1 ); line[i] != '\0'; ++i) /*miss out the space we split on*/ {
      ++offset; /* extra chars on next line, so buffer will be smaller */
      putchar(line[i]);
    }

    return offset;
}
```

**EDIT** Added a return type for `main()`

Comment: I know it's K&R but always give all functions return types.  `main()` is just another (special) function and it should have an explicit return type just like any other.  You _should_ want to anyway for consistency sake.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware that you're re-writing functionality present in the standard library.
This is all right if you're learning, and I would encourage you to continue to do so (it's a great way to learn), but here are a few thoughts from this angle:

`getline` - this is basically `fgets`.

`locate_last_space` - this is what `strrchr(str, ' ')` does. (Note the extra **r** in there means "search in reverse")

`does_line_have_space` - you can use `strchr(str, ' ')` as a boolean expression. (If the result is non-NULL then it has that character.)

`find_split` - it seems a bit redundant to call `does_line_have_space` before `locate_last_space`.  You can use the result of `strrchr(str, ' ')` to determine both that there is a space (result is non-NULL) and where the last space is (using the result as a pointer).

As a style point I would argue that it would be more "C-like" to talk in terms of pointer arithmetic rather than offsets.  (i.e. Take the result of `strrchr`, do something with that pointer, rather than thinking in terms of "give me the offset of the next space".)

Comment: thanks for the advice - now learning the standard library and finding it tremendously useful. found reinventing the wheel to be a useful learning process :)

Comment: @djb - I agree that rewriting these is good to learn.  You might want to try rewriting the functions themselves, conforming to the same interfaces as in the standard library.  For example `strchr` might look like this: `char *strchr(char *s, int c) { while (*s) { if (*s == c) return s; else ++s; } return NULL; }`

Comment: great idea, thanks. i will attempt these when i have covered a bit more ground.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading an entire line, then finding where to break the line, I think I'd read one word, and depending on the length of the line up to that point and the length of the word, decide whether or not to write a new-line before writing that word.

That way, the main loop would come out something like this:

```
while (getword(buffer, max_len)!=EOF) {
    if (current_length + strlen(buffer) > max_len) {
       print("\n");
       current_length = 0;
    }
    print(buffer);
    current_length += strlen(buffer);
}
```

Comment: reading word-by-word seems much more elegant. though wouldn't it break its bounds (and the next line's) if the word were longer than max_len? needing to be able to break mid-word is why i ended up using a split index along with `putchar()`, instead of `printf()` or `print` (which i admit i haven't encountered in the book yet).

Comment: @djb: the idea was to have `getword` only read up to the specified maximum size, so a word in the input that was longer would be broken automatically at that point. And no, `print` is something you won't find in the book -- I was intentionally write this more as C-like pseudo-code than something you'd be able to compile directly.

Comment: ok. I might try and make this program...